# In OpenCV 2.1: How to assign a matrix to a submatrix of another matrix?

Tags: opencv

Assume I have a matrix

```
A = cv::Mat(3,3,CV_32F)
```

and a matrix

```
B = cv::Mat(2,2,CV_32F).
```

Let's say A has all zeros and B has all ones. 
I want to assign the values of B to the upper left corner of A. How can I do this?

I tried the following:

```
A(cv::Rect_<int>(0,0,2,2)) = B
```

But this doesn't seem to work. However assigning a scalar value to the subrect of A this way does work:

```
A(cv::Rect_<int>(0,0,2,2)) = 1.0
```

What is wrong with the first approach?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'd prefer a one-liner, but this does the trick:

```
cv::Mat tmp = A(cv::Rect(0,0,2,2));
B.copyTo(tmp);
```

Comment: I have a indexing doubt about this.  A is 3x3 and Bis 2x2 so if you want to copy B to a, shouldn't you say `cv::Mat tmp = A(cv::Rect(0,0,1,1))` instead?

Comment: It's Rect(x,y, width, height), so Christian's response is correct.  Although, user11094 is more compact.

Answer (score 15):

### Revised answer

I believe the reason your first method

```
A(cv::Rect_<int>(0,0,2,2)) = B
```

doesn't work is because the assignment operator `=` does not copy values but modifies the header of a matrix to point at a submatrix of another. Therefore all this line does is create a temporary header matrix pointing to the submatrix of A, and then replace the header of that temporary matrix to point at B. And then forget about it. The data in A and B remains unchanged.

What you want (although I've not tested it) is

```
B.copyTo(A(cv::Rect_<int>(0,0,2,2)))
```

Comment: But this doesn't generate what the question asker wanted. This generates a Mat A from a sub-range of B, i.e. in that example, A will be 2x2 as well.

Comment: @Ela782 You're right my answer was completely wrong. I've replaced it with a (hopefully) correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in one line with:

```
B = A(cv::Rect(0,0,2,2)).clone();
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't be afraid to work with pointers

```
const unsigned int row_size = col_size = 3;    
Mat A = Mat::one( row_size, col_size, CV_32F );
Mat B = Mat::zeros( row_size, col_size, CV_32F );

for(int i = 0; i < row_size; i++)
{
    float* Aitt = A.ptr<float>(i);
    float* Bitt = B.ptr<float>(i);

    for(int j = 0; j < ( col_size - i ); ++j)
        Aitt[j] = Bitt[j];
}
```

> What is wrong with the first approach?

To many Matlab time

Comment: I'd like a little more compact version ;)