# opencv my own 2D bar code reader

Tags: opencv, barcode, pixel

Didn't find answer in Google, so ask for your help: I need to make C++ program for recognizing 2D own!!! (cipher) bar code (hand made code). It consists of 20-100 lines. Each line - one word.

Desided to use OpenCV. Need find on image group of bars, crop and scan picture from left top corner.

No problem with crop and code searching. Don't understand, how correct recognize line of black and white pixels to get unique combination for each line.

As I anderstand, good way - go by line and see white pixel or black, if black - write 1, if white = 0.... and than write sequence like this:

11111111 000000 111111 00000000000 111111111111111 0000000 1111 = 8 6 6 11 15 7 4 (count 1 and 0 quantity) = get 866111574  than use coefficient depend of crop width and height to find accordance.

How to write this in C++ code using Opencv? Don't understand. Tried to use cvInitLineIterator... What can you advise? Thank you.

Comment: Reason for downvote. No test image and you haven't started learning opencv. There is no code provided by you which makes me doubt you have put proper effort, google "How to iterate image in opencv". If you breakdown every requirement of your project, you will find ample amount of resources on stackoverflow, google etc. Study some tutorials for opencv from here: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/, try python unless you are a lot better in C than python. I would suggest highly answer from Andrew, especially computation of corner and computation of homography before analyzing the bar code.

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided any image or code fragment, so not very clear twat you have now.
Some general thoughts:

1) Search your code corners.

2) Compute homograpy.

3) Apply homograpy transform to get square image of your code.

4) You should know the step of lines of you code (or the number of lines), so just devide image to horizontal lines.

5) Get ROI of every line. Compute sum of pixels along vertical axis (cv::reduce) (to get some statistics). Now you have 1 horizontal line with white and black regions.

6) Devide this line to N pieces (code word length) then compute sum of pixels in every piece.

7) Apply threshold, and you get your code.

Comment: Thank you for answer, code looks like QR code with some differences. About lines: I choose lines quantity (words quantity) before use program in settings. Let it be 100 rows. And there is 10 columnes for barcode. One black bar can use 1 column, can use 2 or 3 column. Also there is different distance between bars. Didn't find in Opencv ability to split image on table. Can adwise something?

Comment: You can set ROI using matrix operations, it is easy, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031233/in-opencv-2-1-how-to-assign-a-matrix-to-a-submatrix-of-another-matrix  But there is another way. If you know locations of data bars you can use mask with bars indexes. Just fill location of bar with values equal to index of this bar. Then you will need just read it, and value of image pixel at the same location.

Comment: How do you think, what method better to use for bar recognizing? My program now can scan photo from top to bottom, drawing ROI rectangle 1 pixel height and 100% width with 1 px step down. I want to use Histogram comparing inside each 1px ROI to find matches with model bar pictures, but will it be enough fast and correct or can advise something better?

Comment: If you know line format of your code, you can scale template to your line and count white or black pixels in each code bit region. If number of on pixels will be over 50% then bit is on, if not, the bit is off.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate trough pixels like this:

```c
uchar pixel = 0;
Mat img; // this must be grayscale image - type CV_8U
for(int i=0; i<img.rows; i++)
{
    // this loop is iterating from left to right
    for(int j=0; i<img.cols; j++)
    {
        pixel = img.at<uchar>(i,j);
        // do something (e.g. sum pixels)
        // OpenCV doesn't have binary image type, so usually white pixels value is 255
    }
}
```

Better solution might be to use [findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) and [minAreaRect](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rotated_ellipses/bounding_rotated_ellipses.html), which should create a rectangle around each line:

```c
vector<vector<Point>> vecContours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
RotatedRect currentRect; 

Mat binaryImage = imread(...)

// binaryImage should contain only shapes or edges, I suggest using one of these approaches:
// simple binary tresholding, try different threshold_value
threshold(binaryImage, binaryImage, threshold_value, 255, THRESH_BINARY);

// adaptiveTreshold works better when image is varying in brightness
// adjust blockSize and C (start with C=0)
adaptiveThreshold(binaryImage, binaryImage, 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, CV_THRESH_BINARY, blockSize, C);

// another option would be to use Canny edge detector: 
// http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html

// find external contours, binaryImage = grayscale 8-bit image
// binaryImage is modified during findContours so we create a clone
findContours(binaryImage.clone(), vecContours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

// find minAreaRect for each contour (each line)
for (size_t = 0; i < vecContours.size(); i++)
{   
    // filter unwanted objects (contours with less than 4 points, contours with too small area)
    if (vecContours[i].size() < 4 || contourArea(vecContours[i]) < someAreaInPixels)
        continue;

    // you can draw contours for debugging
    // drawContours(binaryImage, vecContours, i, Scalar(255,0,0), 1, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());

    RotatedRect minRect = minAreaRect(vecContours.at(i));

    // now you can use minRect.size.width to determine width of the bar
    // minRect contains center point, size and angle
}
```

Comment: Thank you for examples, but "minRect.size.width to determine width of the bar" - that is first question... But what about width of white area between black bars? It is important too. Or, may be need use any mask example to compare line with example?

Comment: You can put the RotatedRect's in a vector and then sort it by _rect.center.x_ coordinate using `std::sort`. So now you have rectangles sorted from left to right. Then you can loop trough and extract distance between them (by using _rect.center.x_ and _rect.width_). If you need help how to sort the vector just ask.

Comment: Now I see you have multi line bar code. In this case the procedure is similar as before, you just need to sort by X and then by Y coordinate. Vector will have sequence of rect's from left to right and from top to bottom.